# Within code called by Resque worker, why is object a hash?

Tags: ruby, resque, feedzirra

I've been unable to work with an object within code triggered from a Resque worker.  This is a sinatra/datamapper app.  The Feed class is a DataMapper model.  Here's the Subscriber code

```
class Subscriber
  @queue = :subscriptions_queue

  def self.perform(feed_id)
    feed = Feed.get(feed_id)
    feed.subscribe()
  end
end
```

Working well, up until the subscribe() method executes

```
class Feed
  def subscribe    
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url)
    raise feed.description
  end
end
```

Which results in an error:

```
** [23:09:44 2012-08-02] 32028: (Job{subscriptions_queue} | Subscriber | [2]) failed: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `description' for #<Hash:0x007fa6f4b97e48>>
```

Why would that be a hash?  I can call inspect on the feed object:

```
class Feed
  def subscribe    
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url)
    raise feed.inspect
  end
end
```

which dumps the feed as one would expect:

```
** [23:01:31 2012-08-02] 32010: (Job{subscriptions_queue} | Subscriber | [2]) failed: #<RuntimeError: {#<Addressable::URI:0x3fefd45f2fb8 URI:http://feeds.feedburner.com/scoutapp>=>#<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSFeedBurner:0x007fdfaa024f18 @title="Scout ~ The Blog", @url="http://blog.scoutapp.com/", @description="Scout ~ The Blog", @hubs=["http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/"], @entries=
```

See any areas to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually an hash with a pair of `Addressable::URI => Feedzirra::Parser::RSSFeedBurner`

if you don't know how to get that URI object just do `feed[feed.keys[0]].description` or `feed.values[0]`

Also checking the github repo it seems you should have a `entries` method. This happens if you are fetching from the root url. So you might be able to do `feeds.entries.first` if you only want to get the first.

Comment: Still seems odd, if I execute the same code in irb, and call .inspect it's just a (not a hash pair)
 => "#<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSFeedBurner:0x007f9b81132170

Comment: Ahh, I see now, my url property on the Feed class is an Addressable::URI, and Feedzirra will return the hash if the url is anything but a string.  In irb, I was using strings.  Thanks for the hint!